# Q: How to fix printer trouble

Tags: usb, printing, epson

I have a ink jet printer named 'epson pm-a890' connected directly via usb.

Ubuntu 19.04 automatically found the printer and configured it.

> Configure
>
> Name: PM-A890
>   Description: EPSON PM-A890
>   Driver: Current - EPson PM A890 - CUPS+Gutenprint v5.3.1

But when I start to print something, the printer prints nothing and it ejects all of the papers. I can't print anything from ubuntu at all. Even test page cant be printed. ubuntu drives the printer eject all of the paper...

On the other hands, Windows 10 can print without any problems via usb.

How to fix the trouble? Where should I check?

Comment: Go to http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX then put your product in there and search. There is a driver dated 8-30-19. Try it. Version 1.7.3

Comment: okay. I'll try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue have fixed. I took the steps below.

1. Download a driver on the site jpezz showed.(Tnx jpezz)
2. Install the driver like below.

   $ sudo dpkg --install epson-inkjet-printer-escpr-1.7.3-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb
3. Run 'Printers' application.
4. Choose 'Add printer' and choose 'Local Printers/EPSON PM-A890(EPSON  PM-A890)' and press 'Next' button.
5. Choose 'Recommended Drivers/Epson PM-A890 - epson-inkjet-printer-escpr 1.7.3-1lsb3.2(Seiko Epson Corporation LSB 3.2)()' for the driver.
6. Name the printer like 'EPSON PM-A890' and press 'Finish' button.

Now I can confirm that the message 'Epson PM-A890 -epson-inkjet-printer-escpr 1.7.3-1lsb3.2(Seiko EPson Corporation LSB 3.2)' is showed for the information of added printer. I could print a test page without problems.

I don't know why the 'Epson PM A890 - CUPS+Gutenprint v5.3.1' driver which ubuntu installed automatically doesn't work properly, but anyway, escpr driver works well.

Comment: If you choose `CUPS+Gutenprint` you install not the driver you've downloaded.